# Powershell IF Statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm having a go at trying to create a quick IF Statement for disabling/ enabling a webcam.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
$InstIDDisabled = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Camname" -Status error
$InstIDEnabled = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Camname" -Status OK
If($InstIDDisabled.Status -eq "error"){
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $InstIDDisabled.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
else
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $InstIDEnabled.InstanceId -Confirm:$false}
```

The result I get is:

```
Get-PnpDevice : No matching Win32_PnPEntity objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity class on the  CIM server: 
SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity  WHERE ((Name LIKE 'Camname')) AND ((Status = 'error')). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:19
+ ... DDisabled = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Camname" -Status erro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Win32_PnPEntity:String) [Get-PnpDevice], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-PnpDevice
```

The error looks like it can't see the webcam by CIM query, but when run individually (removing the IF element) it works.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're missing some braces.  If statement structure is if(<condition){ <positive result> } else { <negative result> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your error is on line 1, but perhaps that is because you've obfuscated the "camname" here.

The problem you're referring to is likely due to your `if/else` statement **not being properly enclosed in braces**:

Also note, I don't think you need to explicitly check for the property of `$InstIDDisabled` equal to "error", because you only returned objects with that property anyway, so you can just check if the variable has anything in the if statment.

```
$InstIDDisabled = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Camname" -Status error
$InstIDEnabled = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Camname" -Status OK
if ($InstIDDisabled) {
    Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $InstIDDisabled.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
} 
else {
    Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $InstIDEnabled.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew, that worked!
I had indeed obfuscated the name of the cam, I'm pretty new to Ifs/ Elses, this has helped a lot.